# Removing a single Item from a mongoDB array using $pull

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to do what the title of the question says. Removing a single item from an array of objects. I am trying to remove a specific object using the `_id (ObjectID)`. I have written this query as it can be seen on the code below :  `$pull: { 'ARRAY': {$elemMatch: {_id: idToRemove}}}`. What happens next may shock you. ALL items from the array are removed...

Here is the code from the nodeJS app that sends the query:

`var findOne = { 'User.username': req.user.User.username };
var query = { $pull: { 'User.Polls': {$elemMatch: {_id: req.body.pollID}}}};
User.findOneAndUpdate(findOne, query, function (err, response) {//EVERYTHING GOT REMOVED});`

Here is a photo of the mongod structure [image: photo]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. I was using User.Polls._id which did not point into the array that i had(Polls). After that I got it to work by selecting the whole document using $elemMatch creating this bug. By removing $elemMatch my problem got solved. That's the final query $pull: { 'User.Polls': {_id: req.body.pollID}}